# $_GET textarea losing HTML characters

Tags: html, forms, get

This is probably a really simple one but I can't find the answer anywhere!

I have a self submitting form with a textarea field like this

```
<textarea name="desc" wrap="1" cols="64" rows="5"></textarea>
```

When I type HTML characters in to the textarea field and hit the submit button, the HTML characters are being stripped and I can't see what is doing it!

Do $_GET variables have their HTML stripped automatically?

For example, If I type '[strong]Just[/strong] a test' in to the textarea, and echo the contents of 'desc' like this

```
echo(print_r($_GET));
```

I see $_GET['desc'] contains 'Just a test' rather than '[strong]Just[/strong] a test'.

Is this normal? If so, is there a way to keep the HTML so I can store it in a database?

I am using angle '<>' brackets rather than square '[]' in my code, but this forum converts them if I use them here!

Comment: if you're displaying it straight from database then the browser is probably doing it. When you echo it try wrapping the php statement in a <pre> and <code> html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use CDATA

> `A CDATA section starts with "<![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>"`

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Answer (score 0):

Where are you printing the data too? The web will parse the html and if you're not looking at the page source you're only going to see the non-html parts.

However, you should be using `print html_entities($_GET['desc'])` to print out the contents with the html content properly encoded so it's printed instead of parsed.

Comment: Looks like there is another script running that is cleaning the $_GET of the HTML values. Sorry for wasting everyone's time and thanks for all your suggestions